# VS2013 R3 NodeJS project slow loading

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2013, typescript

I have a NodeJS project in Visual Studio and it takes more than 2 min when it tries to load the solution and the project.

Looking other questions about performance issues I've disabled the source control, the visual experience and the synchronization:

- Tools > Options > Source Control > Plug-in Selection

  - "Current source control plug-in": None
- Tools > Options > Environment > General

  - "Automatically adjust visual experience based on client performance": Unchecked
  - "Enable rich client visual experience": Unchecked
  - "Use hardware graphics acceleration if available": Unchecked
- Tools > Options > Environment > Synchronized Settings

  - "Enable synchronization for the following categories of settings": Unchecked

None of this actions improved the performance in project loading time.

How can I improve the project loading time? Are there any facts I should take in account to do not delay the loading time?

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Update 3

**Update**

I have figured out what is going on (see accepted answer).

I will accept any other answer that tells me how to prevent folders to be loaded in the explorer tree because I will like to keep this folders there but not for visual studio proposes.

I have tested toggling "Show all files" option in the project explorer tree but it seems to do not affect to the loading time since the explorer tree still needs to process all the files in the directory (even if those are not going to be shown in the explorer tree).

Comment: Is the loading time ok if you load other project type?

Comment: I have created a new project "Basic Express Application" and it loads instantly. I'm testing all the modifications I've made in my project to see if I catch the step that hits the loading performance.

Comment: Interesting. I would try to reproduce this issue later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Visual Studio explorer tree needs time to process all the files in the project folder.

I have tested it with a symbolic link to a folder that contains 184,615 Files and 15,012 Folders (13.7 GB) and the project never gets loaded (at least it does not look like it will become loaded before the next year), so I had to halt it.

Cleaning as much folders and files as possible from my project solved the problem and now the project loads in 3s.